# VBS Script, add a new line in multiple txt

Tags: text, vbscript, numbers, line

I have a bunch of txt files in a folder and I need to add a line to each of them to a specified line number.

```
input box 1 : New lineofText as string.
input box 2 : Line where I want this lineoftext to be inserted, as an integer.
```

All I found was adding text to the top or bottom, like so :

```
Dim FSO, txs, fld, fil, content
newline = inputbox("New line :")
line = inputbox("Which line :")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set fld = FSO.GetFolder("\folderpath")
For Each fil In fld.Files
If Right(fil.Name, 3) = "txt" Then

    Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(1) ' 1 = for reading
    content = txs.ReadAll
    txs.Close

    Set txs = fil.OpenAsTextStream(2) ' 2 = for writing
    txs.Write newline & vbCrLf & content
    txs.Close

End If    
Next
```

to write to the end I simply switch this :

```
txs.Write newline & vbCrLf & content
```

to this :

```
txs.Write content & vbCrLf & newline
```

**But how do I get it to write a new line to a specified line number ?**

---

Edit : user duDE told me I need to count lines with this :

```
Dim nLineToAddTheNewLine : nLineToAddTheNewLine = 5 ' your desired line where you need the new line
line = 5
newline = "blablabla"
filename = "C:\myfile.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

Dim nCount : nCount = 0
Dim sContent : sContent = ""

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
WScript.Echo f.ReadLine
sContent = sContent & f.ReadLine
nCount = nCount + 1
If nCount = line Then sContent = sContent & vbCrLf & newline
Loop
f.Close
```

This code is meant for one file with a straight name.
So at this point I'm having a lot of trouble getting my script to work.
Here is where I'm stuck :

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
'newline = inputbox("New line :")
'line = inputbox("Which line :")
newline = "blablabla"
line = 6
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "Agent-API Blocking Queue Size: [1-9]+[0-9]*"
objStartFolder = "C:\MyfolderWithLotOfFiles\"

Dim lineCount : lineCount = 0
Dim firstContent : firstContent = ""

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
  lineCount = 0
  firstContent = ""
  FileName = objStartFolder & objFile.Name
  WScript.echo FileName
  Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
  Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream
    lineCount = lineCount + 1
    firstContent = firstContent & objStream.ReadLine
    if lineCount = line Then 
        Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting)
        objStream.Write firstContent & vbCrLf & newline & vbCrLf
    End if
  Loop  
  objStream.Close 
Next
```

Script is reading each line of every txt file, but I got an error when I want to write, **please help !**

```
if lineCount = line Then 
    Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting)
    objStream.Write firstContent & vbCrLf & newline & vbCrLf
End if
```

Comment: In your case, i think, you should read your text file line by line and stores them into an array then browse them through a loop for next

Comment: In your last edit you forgot to put this line ==> Const ForWriting = 2

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just edited first post, duDE answered that a few hours ago but it was since deleted. The problem is that I'm fairly new to vbs and don't get this as fast as programmers would, i'm feeling miserible, already 6 hours I'm on a simple txt write script. It would really be kind of you if you could point out my mistake in the last lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to this code :

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
'newline = inputbox("New line :")
'line = inputbox("Which line :")
newline = "blablabla"
line = 6
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\MyfolderWithLotOfFiles\"

Dim lineCount : lineCount = 0
Dim firstContent : firstContent = ""

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in colFiles
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile)) = "txt" Then
        lineCount = 0
        firstContent = ""
        FileName = objStartFolder & objFile.Name
        WScript.echo FileName
        Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)
        Do Until objStream.AtEndOfStream
            lineCount = lineCount + 1
            firstContent = firstContent & objStream.ReadLine & vbCrLf
            if lineCount = line Then 
                firstContent = firstContent & newline & vbCrLf
            End if
        Loop  
        Set objStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForWriting)
        objStream.WriteLine firstContent
        objStream.Close 
    End If  
Next
```